# Store and load fabricjs canvas on server

Tags: javascript, serialization, upload, server, fabricjs

I am creating an app which uses fabricjs canvas drawing comics. Canvas contains some objects such as rectangles, svg object, and jpeg images. After editing is done, the canvas need to be stored in the server (nodejs) and should be reloaded later from server by the creator or other viewers. 
I thought I can serialize canvas to svg string and store svg string on the server and upload images which exist in the canvas one by one to the server as well. Later on, load the svg string replace the images url with the downloaded picture and reload the canvas.

Here are my questions:
 1- Is this the right way to achieve my goal?
 2- I am doing all of this because my canvas will have different size depending on user device (monitor, smartphone,...) therefore, I chose to use svg for scalability. However, I'm not sure how to scale the original svg string to the new canvas.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't save to SVG. SVG is for export. Call `myCanvas.toObject()`
2. Not sure how you're going to take advantage of SVG's scalability, if you are just using SVG as a persistence format for canvas. But if you're going to render in SVG, then that makes sense.

You may be overthinking the image solution. How are users going to put an image on the canvas in the first place? The way I do it is to have them upload the image to my server. Then I let them choose images from an image browser. The image they choose already has a URL, so there's nothing left to do when storing/restoring.

Comment: How is exporting to objects or JSON is useful or scalable? like let's say an object is at 50,50 with width 100 and height 200, in a bigger screen when I load the stored json it's still the same size. So, I guess however, scaling is supposed to be managed for JSON, it's possible for svg as well. And Actually, I am not sure how to do it.Right now I just render svg.

The user might put so many picture on the canvas and I can't just upload everything first. It's a mobile app, so pictures come from camera I can't waste users time and data with uploading so many things and then finally choose one.

Comment: If this is in HTML and JS, then you must be using the File API to get the image bytes from an Image input and creating an image element with a Data URI as the source, right? If so, then the image data is already in the JSON (or SVG -- I don't remember if you can serialize Data URIs to SVG)